# Presenting landscape controller crashes SplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

**Some background:**

The app has a TabBarController. TabBarController has VC1.1 and VC2.1.
The app supports only portrait for iPhone and for 1 screen that we call VC1.2 (that I will mention later) it will show it in landscape mode.
But for iPad we support both portrait and landscape.

VC2.1 is a Controller which has NavigationController. This Screen 2.1 can push the new screen 2.2. Important note is that the screen 2.1 and 2.2 on iPad are presented together in a split view. But on iPhone we present it only separately in 2.1 and 2.2.

So how the crash happens.

1. The crash reproduces only with iPhone+ or X Max.
2. Open VC2.1 and press the button to push VC2.2.
3. Go back to VC1.1 and press button to present the screen VC1.2 that must be in landscape.
4. The app crashes with this info:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
>
> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .
>
> [Assert] Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already. (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController>)
>
> [Assert] transitionViewForCurrentTransition is not set, presentation controller was dismissed during the presentation? (<_UIFullscreenPresentationController)

So what happens is that on VC1.2 we are show the screen that we force to be in landscape mode.
And in VC2.2 (and VC2.1) since there is a SplitView (even though for iPhone it is not used) it somehow tries to rotate it and "show" (or pretend showing) that split view. And it crashes because it can't do it.

So we understand why this happens but can't understand if there is a way to fix it or is it an iOS issue maybe.

If it helps, in AppDelegate we have this method:

```
private func defaultInterfaceOrientations(for window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let isPhone: Bool

    if let window = window {
        isPhone = window.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    } else {
        isPhone = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }

    return isPhone ? .portrait : .all
}
```

**EDIT1**:

There is one very interesting thing that happens in this flow and which may give an additional hint.

Steps:

1. Open VC2.1. Press button to push VC2.2. Press back button (pop).
2. Go to VC1.1. Open the landscape screen V1.2. It won't crash. Meaning it crashes only when VC2.2 is opened, but when VC2.1 is opened - it doesn't crash.
3. The interesting point: when you open the VC2 (tab bar item) you would expect it to be on VC2.1 since we went back (pop). But for some reason it will be on screen VC2.2. So somehow in the "back" it made a push of VC2.2.

Comment: Check your view hierarchy may be it help.

Comment: @iOSTeam thanks for the reply! The thing is that these 2 flows (VC1.. and VC2.. are in 2 different tabs. So they are not even connected). I still double checked the View Hierarchy with view debugger and didn't find anything special.

Comment: So As per your question, it seems to be a very strange issue but as a guess, you can check trait variation, And also check back button events of the VC2.1 because you said that when you open after it is showing VC 2.2